# Insert retorna TRUE, porém não insere

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Estou aprendendo Laravel 6 e fiz um formulário de cadastro (não estou usando o auth do Laravel) e quando eu envio os dados e realizo o insert na tabela ele retorna TRUE, mas quando verifico no Banco de Dados ele não inseriu nada.

Criei meu controller com o seguinte comando

```
php artisan make:controller UserController --resource
```

Meu .env está assim

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=presenceControll
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=1234
```

Meu formulário de envio

```
<form action="/user/cadastrar" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-row">
                    <fieldset class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12"><br>
                        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                        <input required type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="exemplo@exemplo.com">
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12"><br>
                        <label for="text">CPF</label>
                        <input required type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" placeholder="000.000.000-00">
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <fieldset class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                        <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                        <input required type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                        <label for="sobrenome">Sobrenome</label>
                        <input required type="text" class="form-control" id="sobrenome" placeholder="Digite seu sobrenome">
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <fieldset class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <label for="password">Senha</label>
                        <input required type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Digite sua senha">
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <label for="password">Confirmar senha</label>
                        <input required type="password" class="form-control" id="password_confirm" placeholder="Repita sua senha">
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <button required type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">Cadastrar</button><br>
            </form>
```

Minhas rotas de view e envio do formulário

```
Route::get('/user/cadastro', 'UserController@create');
Route::post('/user/cadastrar', 'UserController@store');
```

e por fim meu controller que retorna TRUE no `dd`

```
public function create(){
    return View('/user/cadastro');
}

public function store(Request $request){
    $retorno = \DB::table('user')->insert($request->except('_token'));
    dd($retorno);
}
```

Segui a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x) do Laravel, queria saber o que estou fazendo errado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema é na parte [html](/questions/tagged/html) você não configurou o atributo name, exemplo:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" placeholder="000.000.000-00">
```

cade o `name`?

***Solução:***

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="cpf" id="cpf" placeholder="000.000.000-00">
                                          ^
                                          | (faltou colocar o name)
```

é por esse atributo que é recuperado as informações de todos os `inputs`, então adicione em todos os `inputs` o atributo `name` com o nome respectivo utilizado pela sua lógica.

Comment: Não tinha prestado atenção que era pelo name que recuperava, obrigado!